# Executing a shell command from Common Lisp

Tags: bash, shell, lisp, exec, common-lisp

How can i execute a shell (bash) command within a Common Lisp program and assign the output to a variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) provides a `RUN-SHELL-COMMAND` that works with many Common Lisp implementations** including ABCL, Allegro CL, CLISP, Clozure CL, ECL, GCL, LispWorks, SBCL, CMU, XCL and SCL.

It takes a control string and a list of arguments like `FORMAT`, and synchronously executes the result using a Bourne-compatible shell. Capture output by binding an optional stream.

Comment: Keep in mind, from the [ASDF documentation](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html) for `run-shell-command`: "This function is obsolete and present only for the sake of backwards-compatibility: “If it's not backwards, it's not compatible”. We strongly discourage its use. Its current behavior is only well-defined on Unix platforms (which include MacOS X and cygwin). On Windows, anything goes. The following documentation is only for the purpose of your migrating away from it in a way that preserves semantics."

Comment: if it is deprecated, whats an alternative?

Comment: According to the documentation, run-program is preferred over run-shell-command

Comment: You can find the `run-program` documentation [here](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#index-run_002dprogram) and simple usage examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721081/does-there-exist-standard-way-to-run-external-program-in-common-lisp).

Comment: the alternative seems to be [uiop](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/tree/master/uiop) `run-program` (sync) and `launch-program` (async).

Comment: @ftravers as long as you're only going to programming on POSIX systems then there's nothing wrong with `run-shell-command`.  **It's only** considered **deprecated because** **it doesn't work on Windows**.

Answer (score 13):

ITA has released **inferior-shell** under their QITAB umbrella project.

Some links of possible interest :

- http://common-lisp.net/gitweb?p=projects/qitab/inferior-shell.git
- http://common-lisp.net/projects/qitab/
- http://cliki.net/inferior-shell

A git repository is currently hosted at common-lisp.net :

```
git clone git://common-lisp.net/projects/qitab/inferior-shell.git
```

Comment: In addition to the git repo, `:inferior-shell` is installable through [`quicklisp`](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).

Comment: After reading the posted answers here, I investigated and switched to Inferior-shell because it seems to work on both Linux and Windows, whereas Trivial-shell doesn't seem to work on Windows.

Comment: Note for better understanding: inferior-shell uses [uiop](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/tree/master/uiop)'s function `run-program` (which is synchronous, launch-program is async).

Answer (score 8):

You can consider using **Trivial-shell** ([url](http://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-shell/user-guide.html#shell-command))

```
(trivial-shell:shell-command "echo foo")
```

shell-command returns output, so you can assign it to a variable.

In [asdf.lisp](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.lisp) file you can read:

> ;;;; We probably should move this functionality to its own system and deprecate
>
> ;;;; use of it from the asdf package. However, this would break unspecified
>
> ;;;; existing software, so until a clear alternative exists, we can't deprecate
>
> ;;;; it, and even after it's been deprecated, we will support it for a few
>
> ;;;; years so everyone has time to migrate away from it. -- fare 2009-12-01

Comment: According to the [trivial-shell page on Cliki](http://www.cliki.net/trivial-shell): "NB: These days you might prefer inferior-shell for its wider support and richer interface."

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays I would use `uiop:run-program`, where `uiop` stands for "universal input output" and is a compatibility layer provided by asdf3, formerly known as `asdf/driver`. As has been said `asdf:run-shell-command` is obsolete and uiop inherits many features of other libraries such as `trivial-shell`.

[UIOP readme](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/blob/master/uiop/README.md)

Comment: Your link is **broke**.

Comment: Fixed it, thank you for the note. Btw, that was my first stackoverflow post, I wanted to do a comment first but could not because I needed something like 50 karma (now it seems to work).

Answer (score 7):

In sbcl:

```
(sb-ext:run-program "/bin/sh" (list "-c" "whoami") :input nil :output *standard-output*)
```

It works fine for me:)

Answer (score 5):

Some CL implementations have built-in functions for this purpose.  For example, SBCL has `sb-ext:run-program`, and CCL has `run-program`.

Answer (score 3):

This (appupdate.cl) program is an example of creating and executing a shell script using the Steel Bank Common Lisp (sbcl) implementation, which assumes you have sbcl installed and its in your path.

I wrote this on Ubuntu 14.04 as a simple way to perform the automation of the updating, upgrading, and kernel upgrading of the app/system software.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script
(with-open-file (str "/home/geo/update.sh"
                     :direction :output
                     :if-exists :supersede
                     :if-does-not-exist :create)
  (format str "#! /bin/bash~%~%apt-get update~%~%apt-get upgrade -y~%~%apt-get dist-upgrade -y~%~%exit~%))
(sb-ext:run-program "/bin/chmod" '("+x" "/home/geo/update.sh")
    :output *standard-output*)
(sb-ext:run-program "/bin/bash" '("/home/geo/update.sh")
    :output *standard-output*)
(sb-ext:run-program "/bin/rm" '("-rf" "/home/geo/update.sh")
    :output *standard-output*)
```

So of course it creates a shell script entitled update.sh, which is directed to /bin/bash via shebang (#!). After doing so the sb-ext:run-program built directs a shell to execute /bin/chmod passing the flag "+x" as an argument and the /path/to/the-file. This function changes the mode of access of the file to executable (changes the permissions).

Next, a shell is open and executes /bin/bash and the bash binary is passed the argument of the executable shell scripts file location.

Lastly the file is removed from the working directory (note in this case the appupdate.cl is in my home directory therefore is the working directory).

The appupdate.cl file can be executed from the command line after it is changed to executable and temporary root privileges are gained:

```
:~$ chmod +x appupdate.cl

:~$ sudo bash

:~# ./appupdate.cl

:~# exit
```

Easily enough the sudo command could be added to the script (e.g. sudo apt-get update) and using the sudo bash sequence would not be necessary.

NOTE: In the LispWorks ide on 14.04 the (sys:run-shell-command "") is still applicable even though it has sort of become a 'legacy' function.

Answer (score 2):

I tried out some answers but it was not straightforward.
This is what worked easily:

```
(ql:quickload "external-program")
;; run shell command e.g. "ls -l" and capture the output into string *output*
(defparameter *output* 
              (with-output-to-string (out) 
                (external-program:run "ls" '("-l")  ; command with parameters as list of strings
                                      :output out)))
;; and after that, you can write functions to parse the output ...
```

This is from Edi Weitz's book `Common Lisp Recipes` which belongs to the shelve of any serious Lisp programmer, in my view...