# SBCL Run Shell Command

Tags: python, shell, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I've seen [Executing a shell command from Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6065446/1281433) and its answers, but I'm still not sure whether SBCL provides a way execute shell commands from code.

The [SBCL Manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#sb_002dposix) does support POSIX, but I was hoping for something a bit more higher level. Specifically, I want to call a Python script and capture the return value. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: SBCL Manual: running external programs: http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Running-external-programs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the file `test.py`:

```
import sys
sys.exit(42)
```

You can run it with `sb-ext:run-program` and examine the exit code as follows:

```lisp
CL-USER> (sb-ext:run-program "python" '("test.py") :search t :wait t)
#<SB-IMPL::PROCESS :EXITED 42>
CL-USER> (sb-ext:process-exit-code *)
42
```