# How to use sbcl to use shell command

Tags: shell, common-lisp

I want to programing a function about open the file directly. Like python code:

```
os.system("ls")
```

For example, when I use this function (fun_open "/path/to/file"), the system will open the file use the default app. If file is a .txt, open it with textedit.

How to make it?

----UPDATE 9/24/2015-----

My code is:

```
(defun open_by_system (dir)
  (sb-ext:run-program "/usr/bin/open" (list "-a" "Preview" dir)))
```

and I use it:

```
CL-USER> (open_by_system "~/Desktop/ML.pdf")
#<SB-IMPL::PROCESS :EXITED 1>
```

Nothing else happen

Comment: What do you mean by "default app"? What OS is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SBCL Run Shell Command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956010/sbcl-run-shell-command)

Comment: @ccQpein I think you're confusing two issues here.  One is how to run a shell command (according to other question, use **sb-ext:run-program**).  But then the other behavior you're describing (opening the file with a "default" application) is usually provided by another utility on the system.  E.g., on some Linux machines, you could run `xdg-open file` to open `file` in the "default" viewer/application.  On Windows, I think you can use `explorer file`, and on OS X `open file`.  (But I don't know whether any of those are the *best* options, just ones that have worked for me in the past.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The usual command on windows is `start file`. I'm surprised explorer works.

Comment: @Random832 I'd never spent much time looking into it, but yeah, explorer works for a lot of things ([and it looks like I'm not the only one who's come across it](http://superuser.com/a/844405/240381)).  It does appear that [start](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx) is the better option, though.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you are right, I am not confusing the difference, but my english skill can't express that. Thank you anyway! And now I am searching how to solve the exited code question.

Comment: `"Preview"` is not a useful path. See my example. You might also look at the documentation for `open -a`, to see what it expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at the available libraries on quickdocs:

[link](http://quickdocs.org/search?q=shell)

I recommend you to use inferior-shell available on quicklisp

[link](http://quickdocs.org/inferior-shell/)

loading:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'inferior-shell)
To load "inferior-shell":
  Load 5 ASDF systems:
    alexandria asdf closer-mop named-readtables optima
  Install 4 Quicklisp releases:
    fare-mop fare-quasiquote fare-utils inferior-shell
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/fare-quasiquote/2015-06-08/fare-quasiquote-20150608-git.tgz">
; 15.08KB
==================================================
15,437 bytes in 0.10 seconds (157.03KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/fare-utils/2015-06-08/fare-utils-20150608-git.tgz">
; 31.51KB
==================================================
32,264 bytes in 0.14 seconds (218.80KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/fare-mop/2015-06-08/fare-mop-20150608-git.tgz">
; 2.67KB
==================================================
2,738 bytes in 0.00 seconds (0.00KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/inferior-shell/2015-06-08/inferior-shell-20150608-git.tgz">
; 12.87KB
==================================================
13,182 bytes in 0.00 seconds (12873.05KB/sec)
; Loading "inferior-shell"
[package fare-utils]..............................
[package fare-stateful]...........................
[package fare-quasiquote].........................
[package fare-mop].............
(INFERIOR-SHELL)
```

a simple sample:

```
CL-USER> (inferior-shell:run/ss '(echo (1) "2" (+ 3)))
"1 2 3"
NIL
0
```

a sample with pipes:

```
CL-USER> (inferior-shell:run/ss `(inferior-shell:pipe (echo (+ hel "lo,") world) (tr "hw" "HW") (sed -e "s/$/!/")))
"Hello, World!"
NIL
0
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using UIOP, which provides portable interface to the OS and is universally available as a part of ASDF3:

```
(uiop:run-program "ls")
```

See the docstrings in [run-program.lisp](https://github.com/fare/asdf/blob/master/uiop/run-program.lisp) for details.

If you need more convenience functions, you could take a look at [inferior-shell](http://quickdocs.org/inferior-shell/).

Answer (score 1):

**Mac OS X and SBCL**:

Open a text file in the default text editor application TextEdit:

```
Lisp Machine:~ lispm$ touch /tmp/test.text

Lisp Machine:~ lispm$ sbcl
This is SBCL 1.2.14, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.

* (sb-ext:run-program "/usr/bin/open" '("/tmp/test.text"))

#<SB-IMPL::PROCESS :EXITED 0>
```

Open the file with LispWorks as the text editor:

```
* (sb-ext:run-program
    "/usr/bin/open"
    '("-a"
      "/Applications/LispWorks 7.0 (64-bit)/LispWorks (64-bit).app"
      "/tmp/test.text"))
```

You might want to consult the SBCL manual for such questions. For example the chapter on [Running External Programs](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Running-external-programs).

Comment: **sb-ext:run-program** is the answer that came up in the possible duplicate, [SBCL Run Shell Command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28956010/1281433), too.

Comment: I code the function, but the exit code is 1, and textedit(actually I open pdf it maybe preview.app) don't open.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I'm sorry about that! My target is make OS X open file with App installed in system. I use your solution, and compile good, but nothing happen unless give me "<SB-IMPL::PROCESS :EXITED 1>". For instance, I want open test.pdf by Preview.app with CL. I'm sorry for my english.